# When is Fear the Walking Dead set?

Tags: the-walking-dead, chronology, fear-the-walking-dead

How much time passes between the first episode of *Fear the Walking Dead* and Rick waking up in the hospital?

Comment: The answer I posted has a word-of-god quote specifically stating Rick is in the coma for four to five weeks and that the first season of FTWD ends roughly three weeks into that. So, yes.

Comment: That doesn't change the time frame of the season.

Comment: Your original question does not reference *FTWD*, but my original answer *does*. The showrunner for *FTWD* quotes Kirkman regarding how long Rick was in the coma and then specifies how long the first season of *FTWD* is, and where it lines up.

Comment: @phantom42 - You were right, I hadn't seen your edit, I have voted to close the question.  And not to be picky, but your *original* answer didn't reference FTWD, it only references it now as of a couple of days ago.

Comment: @phantom42 I am reading your answer, and see no reference to FTWD outside of the quote came from the showrunner of FTWD?  There is nothing in there about the time frame of FTWD in relation to TWD.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Read again. "If you count the days of season one of our show, we’re probably around week three [by the end of the season]." Rick is out 4-5 weeks. Rick goes into the coma before the outbreak has started, so FTWD occurs during the first 3-ish weeks of Rick's coma.

Comment: @phantom42 it is not very clear in the quote which show he is talking about at that point.  However, the interview you link does have a very specific answer: the first day of FTWD is the day Rick was shot.  Perhaps add that in.